# How to bind Dynamic Data to JSON request in WEB Performance Test

Tags: asp.net, json, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, web-testing

Content Type : Application/JSON,Charset=UTF-8
String body  : {"Address1":"XYZ"}

I would like to bind Address1 in String Body to XML File (Filename : Addresses.xml)

```
<Property>
  <Address1>XYZ</Address1>
</Property>
```

Binding it as {"Address1":{{Addresses.Property.Address1}}} hasn't been any help.

Comment: This question is unclear. It appears to be specific to a testing tool, but you did not mention what tool you are using. Or what programming language you are using.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Load test